# Replace in Path: Filename in replacement

Tags: intellij-idea

#### Short question

Is it possible to use the filename as replacement in the function `Replace in Path`?

#### Example

In a folder are two files (`a.txt` and `b.txt`).

- `a.txt`:

  > abc = "xyz"
- `b.txt`

  > abc = "zxy"

And I want automatically replace all occurences of `abc = (.*)` to `%FILENAME%.a = $1`.
After the replacement:

- `a.txt`

  > a.abc = "xyz"
- `b.txt`

  > b.abc = "zxy"

Can I do it with IntelliJ?

Comment: Do you have to use IntelliJ for this task? It would be much easier to use command line tools, like `for i in *.txt ; do sed -i "s/^abc/${i/.txt/}.abc/g" $i ; done`

Comment: It would be nice, if IntelliJ can do that. But if IntelliJ can not do that, then I will use an alternative (bash, python, or whatever),